# Run a python script from the python terminal in Python

Tags: python, pycharm

Iam using pycharm and would like to use some variables I want to input at the terminal.

However I cant seem to run a script for the Python terminal in my pyCharm. I have the script called "sample.py" but if try "sample.py", "python sample.py" or "!python sample.py" I do not get the script working. I get something like:

```
>>>test5.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'test5' is not defined
```

Could anybody tell me how I can trigger a script in the python terminal in Pycharm?

Comment: `from test5 import *` .. though you should generally avoid that when writing code, and use `from test5 import my_x_var`, or preferably `import test5` and then `print(test5.my_x_var)`.

Comment: I would recommend to wrap the executed code into function/class and them import it, like @FermiParadox said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) use `import`

```
>>> import test5
```

2) use `exec()`

```
>>> exec(open("test5.py").read())
```

I don't know if this are the right approaches to handle this problem...